# Hp compaq 6510b with Ubuntu & Windows Vista xp / locked out because lost Adim password

Tags: password, restore

I had 2 hp compaq 6510b in 2010, my son needed one for school so gave him one.. He used it maybe 6-months and seen I was selling Blackberry tablets so I gave him that and got the laptop back.

I just set it aside for a few yrs, I needed it yesterday but can't get pass 
Ubuntu Admin. Password he don't remember it either.
I need it bad, I'd appreciate it so much if someone could help me 
Restore it so I can sign in. When I start it his name and photo pops up and  other also pops up.

Thanks Ca.Rob1

Comment: Take a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password.